# JS method calling from object value

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm working on an emulator. The task at hand is an incoming request on a certain endpoint. The request may contain 1-4 options in the req.body.options. The basic design idea is that an object contains the options and the corresponding method calls (as some sort of a sub-router).

```
let dataActions = {
    option1: optionMethod(param1, param2),
    option2: optionMethod2(param1, param2),
    option3: optionMethod3(params),
    option4: optionMethod4(params)
}

for (key in req.body.options) {
...
}
```

The for...in should fire the methods (decoupled in other files) when it finds matching in the request with the dataActions keys. Is there a semantical way, or a detailed design pattern to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you already fire the methods yourself.

```
let dataActions = {
    option1: optionMethod(param1, param2) // <-- this is a function call
}
```

Doing it this way you assign the *result* of `optionMethod()` to `option1`. The above is effectively shorthand for

```
let dataActions = {};
dataActions.option1 = optionMethod(param1, param2);
```

If that helps making it more obvious.

---

You don't want to call the methods immediately. You want to store them for later use. Either store them directly:

```
let dataActions = {
    option1: optionMethod  // <-- this is a function reference
}
```

...or store a function that calls them in some specific way:

```
let dataActions = {
    option1: function () {
        return optionMethod('some', 'parameters');
    }
}
```

now you can use them at a separate time, for example like this

```
Object.keys(dataActions).filter(a => a in req.body.options).forEach(a => {
    var optionMethod = dataActions[a];
    optionMethod();
});
```

Comment: Thank you! You helped me a lot to clear the fog in my head.
For some reason I've missed the fact I've stored the result of the function calls as values. So again, thanks for your help! :)